# How to reshape a dataframe from wide to long with columns that represent duplicated variables?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe, I would like to 'transfer' the values of columns from v3 to v10 in the first two columns v1 and v2, respectively, since they are duplicated variables and their values belong to the first two variables (v1 and v2).

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5,
              v1 = c("infection", "anxiety", "pain", "infection", "aspiration"),
              v2 = c(31, 55, 33, 31, 24),
              v3 = c("aspiration", NA, "ulcer", NA, "pain"),
              v4 = c(26, NA, 43, NA, 20),
              v5 = c("skin", NA, NA, NA, NA),
              v6 = c(25, NA, NA, NA, NA),
              v7 = c("ventilation", NA, NA, NA, NA),
              v8 = c(8, NA, NA, NA, NA),
              v9 = c("gas", NA, NA, NA, NA),
              v10 = c(4, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

I would like to have as output this new df:

```
out <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5),
              v1 = c("infection", "aspiration", "skin", "ventilation", "gas", "anxiety", "pain", "ulcer", "infection", "aspiration", "pain"),
              v2 = c(31, 26, 25, 8, 4, 55, 33, 43, 31, 24, 20))
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Use `tidyr::pivot_longer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ugly and I'm not sure how it works, but it does:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# make life easier for tidyr
names(df)[seq(2, 11, 2)]  <- paste0("cond_", 1:5)
names(df)[seq(3, 11, 2)]  <- paste0("var_", 1:5)

# stops tidyr complaining; if the numerics of var matter, you can change them back later
df <- df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("var"), as.character))

df %>% 
      pivot_longer(-id, names_to = c("var", "v2"), names_sep = "_") %>%
      pivot_wider(c(id, v2), names_from = var) %>% 
      na.omit()
```

Answer (score 3):

Renaming column would be better since it will clearly identify which column belongs to which group. You can then use `pivot_longer` directly by using `names_pattern` argument.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  rename_with(~paste(., c('v1', 'v2'), sep = '_'), -1) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, 
               names_to = '.value', 
               names_pattern = '.*_(\\w+)', 
               values_drop_na = TRUE) -> out
out

#      id v1             v2
#   <int> <chr>       <dbl>
# 1     1 infection      31
# 2     1 aspiration     26
# 3     1 skin           25
# 4     1 ventilation     8
# 5     1 gas             4
# 6     2 anxiety        55
# 7     3 pain           33
# 8     3 ulcer          43
# 9     4 infection      31
#10     5 aspiration     24
#11     5 pain           20
```

Comment: Dear Ronak Shah, would you please give me a slight explanation as how `.value` component coupled with `names_pattern` can lead to the desired output for each column. Since we only have one value for `names_to` sometimes I found it difficult to understand the mechanism.

Comment: For example if there was another string beside `.value` in `names_to` it was obvious that side of the name that `.value` is, contains the value we are trying to measure but here there is only one and I've seen this is quite useful but hard for me to understand sometimes.

Comment: Basically you need as many capture groups as values you have in `names_to`. Since here we have only one value in `names_to` i.e `.value` the capture group captures a word occurring after underscore (`_`) which is either `v1` or `v2` in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much. I totally get it now. First name transformation was a fabulous idea.